# Office Required Properties invalid

Tags: office, dip

I spent several time to search a solution for the error:

**REQUIRED PROPERTIES to save to the server, correct the invalid or missing required properties**

Our users are saving a file with metadata in a site collection. I don't know why but sometimes they are moving the files from one site to another. The problem with this is that the metadata columns could be different to the source site. So most of the time they get the above mentioned error. 
The only thing I found was https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928037 but this is not always the best solution for the users. 
Maybe there's a workaround?
regards michael